# ESP32 RTCWDT_RTC_RESET Error during WiFiManager Initialization

Tags: esp32, wifimanager

I'm geting this error when I upload the program to the ESP32 but what I get in console is this message:

> 12:16:44.738 -> ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
>
> 12:16:44.738 ->
>
> 12:16:44.738 -> rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13
> (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
>
> 12:16:44.738 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
>
> 12:16:44.738 ->
> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
>
> 12:16:44.738 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
>
> 12:16:44.738 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
>
> 12:16:44.738 -> load:0x40078000,len:13964
>
> 12:16:44.738 -> load:0x40080400,len:3600
>
> 12:16:44.738 -> entry 0x400805f0

So, it looks like it is a problem with the WiFiManager library but I don't complete sure. Also can it be a problem with the hardware or an initial configuration? This is the code I'm ussing. It is just for test.

```
#include <WiFiManager.h> 
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>

WiFiManager wifiManager;

class SystemState {
private:
    int ledPinSystemWorking=14;
    unsigned long previousMillis;
    const long interval = 500; // Intervalo de tiempo en milisegundos

public:
    SystemState() {
        pinMode(ledPinSystemWorking, OUTPUT);
    }

    void showSystemState(unsigned long currentTime) {

        if (currentTime - previousMillis >= interval) {
            previousMillis = currentTime;

            // Invertir el estado del LED
            if (digitalRead(ledPinSystemWorking) == LOW) {
                digitalWrite(ledPinSystemWorking, HIGH);
            } else {
                digitalWrite(ledPinSystemWorking, LOW);
            }
        }
    }
};

class WifiMng {
public:
    void begin(const char* apName, const char* apPassword) {

        WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

        bool res = wifiManager.autoConnect(apName, apPassword);

        if (!res) {
            Serial.println("Failed to connect");
            // ESP.restart();
        } else {
            Serial.println("Connected... yeey :)");
        }
    }
};

WifiMng wifiMng;
SystemState sys;

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);
    wifiMng.begin("AutoConnectAP", "password");
}

void loop() {

    unsigned long currentTime = millis();
        
    sys.showSystemState(currentTime);
    Serial.print("hi");

}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ESP32, but that error looks like the watchdog timer expired?  It's possible that initialization is just taking longer to execute than the watchdog is allowing.  If I'm correct, you could try clearing the watchdog before and after initialization.  You could also disable it or extend its time temporarily.  Normally that is a bad idea, but if it is only initialization, this shouldn't be an issue during normal running conditions.